# How to implement ViewController with CollectionView inside?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicontainerview

I am trying to implement a "profile" page in my app which is similar to Instagram profile page
[image: instagram]
[image: wireframe]

But the problem I have is the Cell from UICollectionView below get loaded by -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath
But it load every cells at once ,it does not just load the visible cell as it should. And this is because it is inside scroll view ,the make every cell loads immediately.

The image for cell will be sent from server via API and I want to do a loading when user scroll to 2/3 of page.  And this can be done easily in UICollectionViewController.But I want to know how to do that in ViewController that contain collectionView in lower path.

Please help. I think using Header of CollectionView as an upper part of page might solve the problem.  But I also want to implement that when user tap the button and then the display below change ( just like instagram page).  So I am not sure what direction should I go . Should it be a custom container VC or something else ?

TIA

Comment: Hate to say this, but you're going to have to clarify your question. As it is, it's difficult to understand what you're asking. Also it would be helpful to provide your code and an example of the data you're pulling from your API.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Just put the question in the topic. And actually, my question is pretty clear. I want to put CollectionView inside VC but the problem is all cells load at once because it is inside scrollview. So I would like to know a better way to do this.

Comment: Why are you adding your CollectionView to a ScrollView?

Comment: Because if I just add CollectionView ,it will be scrollable only in the CollectionView's area. I want the whole page to be scrollable. The upper part is View and the lower part is CollectionView and both views are in scrollView

Comment: You want the title bar to scroll with the collection view? That's not how the instagram view works so maybe you need to illustrate that a little better?

Comment: Ok, I will update my question. But it is not the title bar that I want to scroll with collection view. It is the upper view .And the lower view is collectionView

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionView is very versatile.  It can handle the entire view, including the upper part that pertains to the user's profile.The trick is to make use of a "supplementary view" in collection view terms (like a header view in table view terms).

I suggest that you throw away the scroll view and make the collection view do all the work for you.  Just like you register classes for cells, register a view for the user profile portion of your UI using:

```
- (void)registerClass:(Class)viewClass forSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind withReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

And respond to the datasource method:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

By answering the that user profile view.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. That is one solution I have considered before but my problem is I want the capacity to change the view below also. When tap button one it will show CollectionView and if I tap button2 it will show TableView .Something like that .

Comment: So build the TableView and CollectionView and stack them both on top of each other in the ScrollView? Then when a user toggles one or the other, just update (refresh) each with the same data you've already grabbed.

Comment: @remus - There are several ways to get this done, but I think the simplest is to use the collection view exclusively.  Think of tableView as just one sort of collection view layout.

Comment: Yeah, or that - OP mentioned both though, so ... :)